# fetching news from http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&output=rss in flash builder mobile application

Tags: ios, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

I want to fetch news from following source in my flex mobile application:

http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&output=rss

I have tried with following steps:

Step 1: I have inser url in Data --> Connect to Data/Services and then I choose option URL

Step 2: Define List control and Drag & drop Getitems() to it.

Step 3: Now,

getDataResult.token = news.getData(/*Enter value(s) for */ pz, cf, ned, hl, topic, output);

it is ask me to define pz, cf, ned, hl, topic, output parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What asks you to define those variables?  Flash builder?  Or is this a runtime error?  Do you just need to put the comma separated list in quotes?  "pz, cf, ned, hl, topic, output"

Comment: Hey, I have put a "pz, cf, ned, hl, topic, output" still it is an error. Thanks for replying. Which is else way for it?

Comment: What was the new error you got?  What is the API Details of the method you're trying to call?